# Is there an advantage of passing firebase DB operations to Node, or just let the client-side JS handle them?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an app that will use firebase as the database. In particular, the Firestore version.

It seems very simple to use a DB as a service, such as Firebase/Firestore, and read/write data directly from the front-end JS code. On the other hand, I'm familiar with Mongo/Node, where you pass your POST/GET requests to Node and Node reaches out to your database.

I was wondering if there is an advantage to pass the DB operations to my Node (app.js) file via an AJAX RESTful request, or if I should just let the client side JavaScript code access the DB directly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is very common to let the client directly access your Firebase database. In fact, that's why it comes with client-side SDKs for many platforms, and with a [server-side security rules language](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/overview) to control what data each client can access.

But there are definitely use-cases where it makes sense to run database-access code on a trusted environment, such as a server you control or [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/). In that environment you will use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup), which runs with full administrative access to the database and other Firebase services.

In most apps you will see a combination of the clients directly accessing the database, and server-side processes for use-cases that require either elevated permissions, that are running code that the user is not allowed to see, or that require CPU/bandwidth beyond what your client devices are guarantees to have.